# vb user profile access restrictions

Tags: vb.net

I need help with creating a vb login app that has control access restrictions depending on the user profile. I'm already done with my login form

```
Public Class main
    Private Sql As New Control
    Private AuthUser As String
    Public form1
        Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    End Sub

    Private Sub main_Load(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles MyBase.Load
        Button1.Visible = False
    End Sub

    Public Function btn() As Boolean
        If form1.txtusername.text = "" Then
            Return False
        Else

        End If
        Return True
    End Function

End Class
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow, bro. For "control access depending on user profile", you will need to present your effort and if there is an error there, someone can help you. Usually, SO tends to discourage questions that ask "write this code for me". http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Answer (score 0):

The best and latest way to create and manage user profiles and to impose restrictions in .Net is using Membership Provider and role based authorization. Membership is used to provide authentication to the user and Role based authorization is used to authorize and restrict users to certain pages based on roles. Here is an MSDN reference for Membership.

[Membership for VB.Net](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.security.membership(v=vs.110).aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-3). That page also has description and implementation of Role based authorization.